# jQuery doesn't find existing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento

I have the following problem I have a dropdown on my website. But because I wanted to add style to it, I hid it and have a bootsrap dropdown showing over it.

This is my **html** structure:

```
<div class="input-box">
    <select name="super_attribute[139]" id="attribute139" class="required-entry super-attribute-  select selectpicker" style="display: none;">
        <option value="">Maat_dames</option>
        <option value="44" price="0">s</option>
        <option value="43" price="0">m</option>
        <option value="42" price="0">l</option>
        <option value="41" price="0">xl</option>
        <option value="40" price="0">2xl</option>
        <option value="39" price="0">3xl</option>
        <option value="38" price="0">4xl</option>
    </select>
   <!-- The normal dropdown -->

   <!-- The bootstrap dropdown -->
   <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select required-entry super-attribute-select">
       <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="attribute139" title="Maat_dames">
           <span class="filter-option pull-left">Maat_dames</span>
           <span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
       <div class="dropdown-menu open">
           <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
               <li data-original-index="0" class="selected">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Maat_dames</span>">
                         <span class="text">Maat_dames</span>
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
           </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to change the text `Maat_dames` to simply just `Maat`, I've tried the following **jQuery** code:

```
if(jQuery('span .filter-option').length == 0){console.log("fail")}
if(jQuery('span .filter-option.pull-left').length == 0){console.log("fail")}
if(jQuery('span .filter-option .pull-left').length == 0){console.log("fail")}
```

When I check the console log, it returns fail in all three cases, so the element isn't found. Why is that the case?

**EDIT**

All the answers suggest removing the space between `span` and `.filter-option` and while it doesn't work on my site, it does work when I try to run the code snippets in the comments en when I try to recreate it in a JSFiddle.

Could it be the case that jQuery can't find the element since it is dynamically created by a plugin?

Comment: Space between span and .filter-option is issue. Remove it so it is span.filter-option because it says span element with that class. If You add space between You are looking for element with class .filter-option somewhere inside of span element

Answer (score 4):

You are using a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) (a space).

`span .filter-option` means any element that is a member of the class *filter-option* and has an **ancestor** that is a *span*.

The only elements which are members of that class in your document are spans themselves and do not have ancestors that are also spans.

Remove the spaces from the selectors.

```js
if(jQuery('span.filter-option').length == 0){console.log("fail")}else{console.log('success'); }
if(jQuery('span.filter-option.pull-left').length == 0){console.log("fail")}else{console.log('success'); }
if(jQuery('span.filter-option.pull-left').length == 0){console.log("fail")}else{console.log('success'); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-box">
    <select name="super_attribute[139]" id="attribute139" class="required-entry super-attribute-  select selectpicker" style="display: none;">
        <option value="">Maat_dames</option>
        <option value="44" price="0">s</option>
        <option value="43" price="0">m</option>
        <option value="42" price="0">l</option>
        <option value="41" price="0">xl</option>
        <option value="40" price="0">2xl</option>
        <option value="39" price="0">3xl</option>
        <option value="38" price="0">4xl</option>
    </select>
   <!-- The normal dropdown -->

   <!-- The bootstrap dropdown -->
   <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select required-entry super-attribute-select">
       <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="attribute139" title="Maat_dames">
           <span class="filter-option pull-left">Maat_dames</span>
           <span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
       <div class="dropdown-menu open">
           <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
               <li data-original-index="0" class="selected">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Maat_dames</span>">
                         <span class="text">Maat_dames</span>
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
           </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `jQuery('span .filter-option')` with `jQuery('span.filter-option')`.

Currently `jQuery('span .filter-option')` is finding element with class **filter-oprion** inside **span** tags in DOM.

When you write `jQuery('span.filter-option')` it will find **span** elements with class **filter-option** in DOM.

Comment: The element still isn't found

Comment: can you reproduce it in fiddle demo?

Answer (score 0):

`('span.filter-option').length` maybe?

Comment: So if you post an answer at the same time as others, you'll get a downvote?

Comment: i am not downvoter but your answer is not complete, add why OP code not working and why this one working

Comment: If you post one which is improperly formatted, reads like a game of spot-the-difference, lacks any explanation as to why it is the solution, and indicates that it is a guess… yes.

Comment: @Quentin It still answers the question, nonetheless.

Comment: Since the question asks "Why doesn't this work?" and not "What do I need to do to fix it?", it doesn't even answer the question. Even if that had been the question, it still isn't a *good* answer to it.

Comment: Both are the same thing. Stop being so pedantic. And it's not hard to find the difference in 3 lines of code. Anyhow that's your opinion, the OP decides what they want.